# How one can see what application link in the applications page based on their access rights and roles in keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I have created 5 clients: Jenkins, Redmine, Gitlab, Jitsi, OnlyOffice in Keycloak. All this clients are shown in application section where account console is shown by default.

i created 2 groups like super-user-groups and normal-user-groups. i created 3 users named super-user who belongs to super-user-groups, normal-user who belongs to normal-user-groups and access-denied-user does not below to any of the groups.

i want to display all clients that i created to users belonging to super-user-groups in application list and for users of normal-user-groups i want to display only Jenkins and Redmine in application list and for access-denied-user i should not display any client that i created in application list.

How can i can do it in Keycloak ,please provide the answers in details steps?

i am facing issue in client configuration

i am not able to list application based on users group